# How to make all values in an boolean array TRUE?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the most elegant way to set all the values in an already defined array to `true` or `false`? I am thinking of not using a `for` loop.

I am currently using the idea of reinitializing the array with only `TRUE` values and I am curious if better methods exist.

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: The code should be in Swift.

Comment: You're going to have to iterate through all the values regardless. Why isn't a `for` applicable?

Comment: I am searching for a more compact version in order to make my code cleaner.

Comment: Can't understand the downvotes. This question is surely interesting for me. As a workaround now I am reinitializing the array to `false` everytime, which surely isn't the best method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach since you don't like the more efficient answer given by Martin using `array = Array(repeating: true, count: array.count)`.

```
var boolArr = [true, false, false, true] // your existing array
boolArr = boolArr.map { _ in true }
```

Comment: Only slightly simpler `boolArr = boolArr.map { _ in true }`.

Comment: The comment one is better. Post it as an answer and I will select it.

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru You really should use the answer by Martin. That's way more efficient than using `map`.

Comment: Your comment reduced verbose. Better as in cleaner. Thanks, I think I'm done with this question. Even better would've been not to have to mention the `_ in`, but meh.

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru The `_ in` is required. It won't compile without it.

Answer (score 5):

You can assign a new array of `true` values with the same element count:

```
var array = [true, false, false]

array = Array(repeating: true, count: array.count)
print(array) // [true, true, true]
```

but interestingly, assigning `true` values in a for loop

```
for i in array.indices { array[i] = true }
```

is much faster. Here is a simple benchmark:

```
let N = 1_000_000

do {
    var array = (1...N).map { _ in arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 }

    let start = Date()
    array = Array(repeating: true, count: array.count)
    let end = Date()
    print("Assign new array:", end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}

do {
    var array = (1...N).map { _ in arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 }

    let start = Date()
    array = array.map { _ in true }
    let end = Date()
    print("Using map():     ", end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}

do {
    var array = (1...N).map { _ in arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 }

    let start = Date()
    for i in array.indices { array[i] = true }
    let end = Date()
    print("Using for-loop:  ", end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}
```

Result (on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook, compiled in Release
mode):

```
Assign new array: 0.00120103359222412
Using map():      0.00364589691162109
Using for-loop:   0.000528931617736816
```

Comment: This is what I am using right now and I can confirm that it's working. I'm also looking for other versions, if possible. Thank you!

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru:  *"This is what I am using right now"* – that would have been a valuable information in your question. You only mentioned a for-loop.